# Rails factory_girls and validation issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have HABTM association

my models

```
 class Ssr < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :ssr_groups
    validates :ssr_groups, presence: true
 end

class SsrGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :ssrs, dependent: :destroy
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

my factories

```
  FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :ssr do
    type 'type' 
    ssr_groups
   end
 end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :ssr_group, class: 'SsrGroup', aliases: [:ssr_groups] do
    name { SecureRandom.hex }
  end
end
```

My problem is when i want to create `FactoryGirl.create(:ssr)`

i have got `NoMethodError: undefined method each for #<SsrGroup:0x007fbfdf792100>`

Why it happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thee problem is that your `ssr` factory is expecting a collection of `ssr_group`, and what you are doing is getting just one. That's why the error, because it's trying to do foreach on the created ssr_group.

To fix this, you can do something like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :ssr do
    type 'type' 
    after(:create) do |ssr, evaluator|
      create_list(:ssr_group, 1, ssrs: [ssr])
    end
  end
end
```

You can use the `build` strategy instead of the `create` if preferred.

**EDIT:**

You can improve your factory a little, like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :ssr do
    type 'type' 

    factory :ssr_with_groups do
      transient do
        groups_count 5 # Default count of ssr_groups it will create
      end

      after(:create) do |ssr, evaluator|
        create_list(:ssr_group, evaluator.groups_count, ssrs: [ssr])
      end
    end
  end
end
```

That way, it's more flexible and you can use it like this:

```
create(:ssr_with_groups, groups_count: 10)
```

And it would create a ssr with 10 ssr_groups.

**EDIT 2:**

Given you have a presence validation on the association, you need to add the associations before saving the object, so use the build strategy instead, like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :ssr do
    type 'type' 
    after(:build) do |ssr, evaluator|
      ssr.ssr_groups << build_list(:ssr_group, 1, ssrs: [ssr])
    end
  end
end
```

You can take a deeper look at the docs: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Associations

Comment: i have tried you solution and now i have got `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Ssr groups can't be blank
`

Comment: You're right, I missed the presence validation, see my EDIT 2.